# correlation between arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, vector, correlation

I have 2 arrays.

```
 a1 = [1,2,4]
 a2 = [3,4,5]
```

how would I find the correlation between these 2 arrays using python.

In matlab, you would do:

```
corr(a1,a2)
```

How to do this in python?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need [`numpy.corrcoef`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html):

```
In [8]:

np.corrcoef(a1,a2)
Out[8]:
array([[ 1.        ,  0.98198051],
       [ 0.98198051,  1.        ]])
```